# PowerPoint 2013 VSTO Undo-Redo CustomerData or CustomXMLPart manipulation

Tags: vsto, undo-redo, powerpoint-2013

I'm building a PowerPoint VSTO addin where I store a lot of metadata on the presentation.

I'm currently storing it as XML as either manipulating `AddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.CustomXMLParts` for global data and `Slide.CustomerData` for slide specific information.

The problem is that neither of them is represented on the Undo/Redo stack. I can make a quintrillion changes to the presentation and modify my Custom XML at the middle somewhere, undo everything and still read back the XML I have last set.

Since I want my modifications to be Undo/Redoable, the best I could think of is storing the XML on a Shape and delete+recreate it on every modification. The problem with this is that the user can obliviously delete the shape or the slide the shape is stored on.

I need something less visible (to prevent accidental removal) and - preferably global - object on the presentation that I can store my XML on that is deletable/recreatable and modifies that Undo/Redo stack.

**Is there something like this?**

**Or is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: Hi @vinczemarton I have a small doubt. How can you able to list all the customXML present in a shape. I created with shape.CustomerData.Add() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

There is [Tags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744602.aspx)!

When you add something to it with `Tags.Add("Name", "Value")` it is properly undoable, unlike `CustomerData` or `CustomXMLParts`.

Tags is present on the presentation and on the slides so both of my scenarios are covered.